# Calling helper function in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function which i am using across the `application` in my controllers.

```
function hideErrorMessage() {
    var error = {};
    error.value = false;
    error.errorMessage = "";
    $scope.error = error;
}
```

How could i put this in a separate file and reference it across the application from there?

Below is a simple service i have created.

```
myApp.service('utilService', function() {
    this.hideErrorMessage= function() {
        var error = {};
        error.value = false;
        error.errorMessage = "";
        return error;
    };
});
```

My worry is i am using this helper function in many places, if i return an `error object` and then assign it to my `$scope.error = utilService.hideErrorMessage()` in my controller, will it be a costly operation.

I am using the `hideErrorMessage()` in multiple places in a same file to hide error message when it passes.

Comment: why do you think it's a costly operation? it's way how we inject service.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal: Just imagine in my controller, if i have $scope.error = utilService.hideErrorMessage() in multiple places just to hide.... i was thinking on these lines.

Comment: service and factory are meant for this ,

Comment: The service itself is a singleton, so you are really just making a basic function call each time. Seems reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a script tag with your file containing your service to the html that has your ng-app directive.  Be sure to add it after the script tag for the angular library.